# Prevent VSCode from saving python debugger command in bash history

Tags: python, bash, visual-studio-code

When I run the Python debugger from VSCode, it floods my bash history with the command:

```
cd /home/maumau/workspace/projects/spreadsheetapi ; env "FLASK_APP=/home/maumau/workspace/projects/spreadsheetapi/app.py" "PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1" /home/maumau/.virtualenvs/spreadsheetapi/bin/python /home/maumau/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2018.9.2/pythonFiles/experimental/ptvsd_launcher.py 45567 /home/maumau/.virtualenvs/spreadsheetapi/bin/flask run --no-debugger --no-reload
```

How could I avoid this?

### [NOT A DUPPLICATE]

Before asking this question, I've searched on man places how to prevent commands from being inserted into history. I've seen many saying that I should use a space in front of the command. My question is not "How to prevent commands from being inserted into bash history" as this has already been answered in previous posts. My question is how to make VSCode do this.

Comment: FYI you can't avoid this on the VS Code side, so you will need a Bash-specific solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will help:

> `"debug.console.historySuggestions"` setting
>
> It is now possible to turn off debug console history suggestions via
>   `debug.console.historySuggestions` which by default is `true`.

See v1.43 release notes:  https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_43.md#debugconsolehistorysuggestions-setting